# Como fazer a sombra em um texto

Tags: html, css

Bom dia, em um projeto que estou desenvolvendo ele tem um tipo de "sombra" para deixar um texto branco mais visível dentro da imagem, o problema é que já tentei ambos Text-Shadow e Box-Shadow na div do texto mas não se tem o resultado esperado, o Text conseguiu colocar uma sombra mas uma sombra não tão destacada.
Gostaria de uma ajuda em como proceder, eis abaixo a imagem do Wireframe do site, o HTML, e o CSS.

**Wireframe:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.item-segmento {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 25px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item-segmento span {
  transition: all .5s ease;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000000;
}

.img-segmento {
  height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.img-segmento>img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.img-segmento .segmento-titulo {
  transition: all .5s ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  display: table;
  color: #FFF;
}

.item-segmento .segmento-titulo>div {
  color: #FFF;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-segmento col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <a href="segmento.php?id=1">
    <div class="img-segmento">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.">
      <div class="segmento-titulo">
        <div>
          <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Alex tem com vc editar a pergunta e colocar uma imagem de como vc gostaria que ficasse? Pq pelo que parece o text-shadow já está funcionando, só não deu para entender o efeito que vc pretende.

Comment: Anderson o jeito que eu quero que fique, é justamente igual a o que está no Wireframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que a melhor forma para esse efeito não é com text-shadow e sim colocando um radial-gradiente por traz do texto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na classe .img-segmento .segmento-titulo vc coloca o gradiente no fundo, indo do preto para transparente. Depois disso vc coloca o text-shadow menor para dar mais definição nas letras. Vc pode controlar o tamanho e a cor do radial-gradiente nessa propriedade

background-image: radial-gradient(at center, rgba(0,0,0,0.95) 0%,transparent 50%, transparent 50%);

Ficaria assim o ajuste.

```css
  .item-segmento {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 25px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .item-segmento span {
    transition: all .5s ease;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #000000;
  }
  
  .img-segmento {
    height: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .img-segmento>img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
  
  .img-segmento .segmento-titulo {
    transition: all .5s ease;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    display: table;
    color: #FFF;
    background-image: radial-gradient(at center, rgba(0,0,0,0.95) 0%,transparent 50%, transparent 50%);
  }
  
  .item-segmento .segmento-titulo>div {
    color: #FFF;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="item-segmento col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <a href="segmento.php?id=1">
    <div class="img-segmento">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.">
      <div class="segmento-titulo">
        <div>
          <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Você tem meus sinceros agradecimentos amigo, abraço!

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado

Answer (score 1):

Tente

```
text-shadow: 2px 2px #FF0000;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use o atributo em seu css

para texto use

```
text-shadow: 0 0 3px #000;
```

para divs use

```
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
```

é bom você da uma estudada sobre esses atributos para facilitar na edição de seus estilos.

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente o **text-shadow** está funcionando, se não gostou do resultado eu recomendo você utilizar filtros, como no exemplo:

[image: Filtro de brilho]

Na segunda imagem eu apenas utilizei o `filter: brightness(60%);`, assim o texto fica mais visível.